# Assign a token before root service initialize

Tags: angular, ngrx

Using angular 10 and NGRX.

I am receiving an access token to a third party library from an API. When receive I store it in my NGRX store (that sync in local storage) to reuse at next reloads.

The problem is, some of my Service provided in root use that token when they are constructed. and I need this token to be setup at the earliest time possible, before my services are constructed.

right now, I put this in my app.component.ts constructor

```
    this.store$.pipe(select(apiToken)).subscribe((token) => {
      Cesium.Ion.defaultAccessToken = token;
    });
```

Now, this trigger before all of my service constructor, but I don't know if it's luck, or if it will be always be the case.

What is a way I could be sure that the token is set before calling it from the services ?

I was thinking to make a initialize method in all the service, and call them from a controller somewhere, but it's kind of annoying, so I wonder if there is some life cycle certainty

Answer (score 0):

Look at APP_INITIALIZER to initialize at startup